# Is there a better way to store a list of strings in an applications config file than using a StringCollection?

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have a list of filenames I need to store in my applications config file.

The only collection that comes up in the initial combo box on the settings page is `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. Now initially I didn't query this as I converted this to a `List<string>` straight away. There was one piece of code I wasn't happy with which was the copying of this list to and from the `ListBox` on the configuration dialog:

```
public List<string> ImageNames
{
    get
    {
        return folderImages.Items.ToList();
    }
    set
    {
        folderImages.Items.AddRange(value.ToArray());
    }
}
```

However, I've been revisiting my code and thought that if I kept the list as a `StringCollection` I could improve this code. Everywhere else I used the list/collection was OK, but this conversion still isn't to my liking:

```
public StringCollection ImageNames
{
    get
    {
        var names = new StringCollection();
        names.AddRange(folderImages.Items.ToList().ToArray());
        return names;
    }
    set
    {
        value.ToList().ForEach(imageName => folderImages.Items.Add(imageName));
    }
}
```

Actually, now I see the code side-by-side (as it were) I'm thinking that the `List<string>` version is "cleaner" - it's certainly clearer.

So is there another collection or list type I can store in the settings file? I'd really like to avoid the conversion on reading and writing the settings file if at all possible.

Failing that - is there a cleaner way of converting between a `StringCollection` and an `ListBox.ObjectCollection` (the `ListBox.Items`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I actually reverted to my original code, but with much cleaner conversions between the `StringCollection` and `List<string>` - the ugliness of which was my starting point.

So now on start up I have:

```
possibleImageNames = Properties.Settings.Default.Images.ToList();
```

and on shut down (where I update the config file) I have:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Images.Clear();
Properties.Settings.Default.Images.AddRange(possibleImageNames.ToArray());
```

Where the `ToList` method on the `StringCollection` is an extension method - used to encapsulate the looping code.

Comment: i still recommend using an object, then you can just go at the top of your app, `using PS = Properties.Settings;` and then just use (List<string>)PS.Default.Images etc

Comment: @sniperX - you're probably right which is why I upvoted your answer, but I don't have the time to pursue this at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a System.Object into the app's settings, its not in the initial combo box, but it is there, then you can just store your data directly to and from the object.

Comment: @Sniper - I haven't forgotten this, I just haven't had the time to revisit the problem. I will try this and if it works accept your answer.

Comment: @sniperX - In the end I actually reverted to my original code, but with much cleaner conversions between the `StringCollection` and `List<string>` - the ugliness of which was my starting point.